# Magento 2 new theme install problem

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend

I have added a new theme from sample theme module : ( parent theme is luma)
 https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-theme

But **it only shows blank page, no product is shown.**
 Do you know why ? How to fix it.

[image]

Comment: How you get products in homepage? Widgets, blocks, etc. Please check the current Design Theme for these.

Comment: I thought that we do not need to add widgets for new child theme. But I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set parent theme as luma but in your theme you have to define your separate Widgets same as defined in luma theme.

In luma theme all homepage and main category listing page render using widget so you have to make widget for your theme specific.
You can check it inside admin panel,
Go to admin,

Click on left navigation, `Content -> Widgets`
You have checked it for luma theme widgets.

You can simply get same homepage like Luma theme using below code adding into your homepage.

```
Content -> Pages
```

Go to your homepage and set below code inside it,

```
<div class="blocks-promo"><a class="block-promo home-main" href="{{store url=""}}collections/yoga-new.html"> <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/home/home-main.jpg"}}" alt="" /> <span class="content bg-white"> <span class="info">New Luma Yoga Collection</span> <strong class="title">Get fit and look fab in new seasonal styles</strong> <span class="action more button">Shop New Yoga</span> </span> </a>
<div class="block-promo-wrapper block-promo-hp"><a class="block-promo home-pants" href="{{store url=""}}promotions/pants-all.html"> <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/home/home-pants.jpg"}}" alt="" /> <span class="content"> <strong class="title">20% OFF</strong> <span class="info">Luma pants when you shop today*</span> <span class="action more icon">Shop Pants</span> </span> </a> <a class="block-promo home-t-shirts" href="{{store url=""}}promotions/tees-all.html"> <span class="image"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/home/home-t-shirts.png"}}" alt="" /></span> <span class="content"> <strong class="title">Even more ways to mix and match</strong> <span class="info">Buy 3 Luma tees get a 4th free</span> <span class="action more icon">Shop Tees</span> </span> </a> <a class="block-promo home-erin" href="{{store url=""}}collections/erin-recommends.html"> <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/home/home-erin.jpg"}}" alt="" /> <span class="content"> <strong class="title">Take it from Erin</strong> <span class="info">Luma founder Erin Renny shares her favorites!</span> <span class="action more icon">Shop Erin Recommends</span> </span> </a> <a class="block-promo home-performance" href="{{store url=""}}collections/performance-fabrics.html"> <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/home/home-performance.jpg"}}" alt="" /> <span class="content bg-white"> <strong class="title">Science meets performance</strong> <span class="info">Wicking to raingear, Luma covers&nbsp;you</span> <span class="action more icon">Shop Performance</span> </span> </a> <a class="block-promo home-eco" href="{{store url=""}}collections/eco-friendly.html"> <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/home/home-eco.jpg"}}" alt="" /> <span class="content bg-white"> <strong class="title">Twice around, twice as nice</strong> <span class="info">Find conscientious, comfy clothing in our eco-friendly collection</span> <span class="action more icon">Shop Eco-Friendly</span> </span> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="content-heading">
<h2 class="title">Hot Sellers</h2>
<p class="info">Here is what`s trending on Luma right now</p>
</div>
<p>{{widget type="Magento\\CatalogWidget\\Block\\Product\\ProductsList" products_per_page="8" products_count="8" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:3:`sku`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`()`;s:5:`value`;s:60:`WS12, WT09, MT07, MH07, 24-MB02, 24-WB04, 241-MB08, 240-LV05`;]]"}}</p>
```

Remove var folder and try your homepage is set now.

Comment: You have mentioned the url link as "{{store url=""}}collections/yoga-new.html" where is yoga-new.html page defined.